# How to create clickonce deployment package for Dot net widnows application using build.cake?

Tags: clickonce, cakebuild

Is there way to handle dot net **clickonce publish** using cake **file** instead of publish wizard?

Answer (score 0):

Cake does not do this, MSBuild does. Cake only starts MSBuild using the required parameters.

Assuming you have [set up your project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/building-clickonce-applications-from-the-command-line?view=vs-2022#publish-properties) to be deployed as a ClickOnce application, the deployment can be started from the command line using  `msbuild /t:publish /p:PublishProfile=<pubxml file> /p:PublishDir="<specific location>"`. (See the docs, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/building-clickonce-applications-from-the-command-line?view=vs-2022#build-net-clickonce-applications-from-the-command-line).)

Hence, if you can publish from the command line as described above, you can use  [`DotNetPublish` in Cake](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Tools.DotNet/DotNetAliases/FB0A1802) to start the publish process.